# Image Icon wont display on button

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton

Hi there I need some help figuring out what's going on with my program. it's supposed to have a panel of letters on the button that has an icon of the letter on it but nothing is coming up. 
All the buttons are showing just without their pictures, this is how i'm trying to get the image.

```
    JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(); // hold 8 letters
    firstPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    aButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images\\a.gif"));
    firstPanel.add(aButton);
```

In my src folder there is another folder names images and a gif in there called a.gif

This is what is being displayed.

[In those boxes on the bottom is where letters are supposed to be stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO9ml.png)

EDIT: I think I ought to add the rest of my code, it is huge though.

```
/*******************************************************************************      **
  * Panel class creates all the buttons for the game including
  * start, stop, next game, and 26 alphabet letters
  * This class also has methods to listen to mouse and keyboard.
   *
   *******************************************************************************      **/

  import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.applet.*;

class LearningPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
long totalLetters;
int  rightButton = 0,
     wrongButton = 0;

String player;
public LearningLetterPanel lp;
private JTextArea letterTextArea;
private JTextField rightButtonTextField,
                   wrongButtonTextField;
private JLabel rightClickLabel,
               wrongClickLabel;

private JButton aButton,
                bButton,
                cButton,
                dButton,
                eButton,
                fButton,
                gButton,
                hButton,
                iButton,
                jButton,
                kButton,
                lButton,
                mButton,
                nButton,
                oButton,
                pButton,
                qButton,
                rButton,
                sButton,
                tButton,
                uButton,
                vButton,
                wButton,
                xButton,
                yButton,
                zButton,
                startButton,
                scoreButton,
                quitButton,
                stopGameButton;

private AudioClip audioClip;
        URL audioUrl;


public LearningPanel(String player) {
    ImageIcon playIcon;
    ImageIcon stopIcon;
    this.player = player;
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // start, next game, quit button
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

     playIcon = new ImageIcon("images\\play.gif");
    startButton = new JButton("Start", playIcon);
    startButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(startButton);

    stopIcon = new ImageIcon("images\\stop.gif");
    stopGameButton = new JButton("Stop", stopIcon);
    stopGameButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(stopGameButton);

    quitButton = new JButton( "Quit",new ImageIcon("images\\Shutdown.gif"));
    quitButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(quitButton);

    JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel();
    scorePanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    scorePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    buttonPanel.add(scorePanel);

    rightClickLabel = new JLabel("Right: ");
    scorePanel.add(rightClickLabel);

    rightButtonTextField = new JTextField(3);
    rightButtonTextField.setEditable(false);
    rightButtonTextField.setFocusable(false);
    scorePanel.add(rightButtonTextField);

    wrongClickLabel = new JLabel("Wrong: ");
    scorePanel.add(wrongClickLabel);


    wrongButtonTextField = new JTextField(3);
    wrongButtonTextField.setEditable(false);
    wrongButtonTextField.setFocusable(false);
    scorePanel.add(wrongButtonTextField);

    this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // letters panel display 26 letters
    JPanel lettersPanel = new JPanel();
    lettersPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    lettersPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(); // hold 8 letters
    firstPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel(); // hold 9 letters
    secondPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    JPanel thirdPanel = new JPanel();  // hold 9 letters
    thirdPanel.setBackground(Color.white);

    aButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images\\a.gif"));
    bButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images\\b.gif"));
    cButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images\\c.gif"));
    dButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images\\d.gif"));
    eButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images\\e.gif"));
    fButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/f.gif"));
    gButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/g.gif"));
    hButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/h.gif"));
    iButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/i.gif"));
    jButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/j.gif"));
    kButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/k.gif"));
    lButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/l.gif"));
    mButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/m.gif"));
    nButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/n.gif"));
    oButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/o.gif"));
    pButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/p.gif"));
    qButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/q.gif"));
    rButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/r.gif"));
    sButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/s.gif"));
    tButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/t.gif"));
    uButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/u.gif"));
    vButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/v.gif"));
    wButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/w.gif"));
    xButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/x.gif"));
    yButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/y.gif"));
    zButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/z.gif"));

    firstPanel.add(aButton);
    firstPanel.add(bButton);
    firstPanel.add(cButton);
    firstPanel.add(dButton);
    firstPanel.add(eButton);
    firstPanel.add(fButton);
    firstPanel.add(gButton);
    firstPanel.add(hButton);


    secondPanel.add(iButton);
    secondPanel.add(jButton);
    secondPanel.add(kButton);
    secondPanel.add(lButton);
    secondPanel.add(mButton);
    secondPanel.add(nButton);
    secondPanel.add(oButton);
    secondPanel.add(pButton);
    secondPanel.add(qButton);

    thirdPanel.add(rButton);
    thirdPanel.add(sButton);
    thirdPanel.add(tButton);
    thirdPanel.add(uButton);
    thirdPanel.add(vButton);
    thirdPanel.add(wButton);
    thirdPanel.add(xButton);
    thirdPanel.add(yButton);
    thirdPanel.add(zButton);

    lettersPanel.add(firstPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    lettersPanel.add(secondPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    lettersPanel.add(thirdPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //change the size of the alphabet Letters and stopGameButton
    aButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    bButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    cButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    dButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    eButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    fButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    gButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    hButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    iButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    kButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    lButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    mButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    nButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    oButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    pButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    qButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    rButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    sButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    tButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    uButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    vButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    wButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    xButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    yButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    zButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));

    stopGameButton.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(120, 40));

    // add listener to the buttons
    this.add(lettersPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    aButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter(); // get random dropping letter
                    matchingLetter(rl, "A");    // compare dropping letter with button leter
                    }
            }
        );
        bButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "B");
                }
            }
        );
        cButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "C");
                }
            }
        );
        dButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter(); // get random dropping letter
                    matchingLetter(rl, "D");    // compare dropping letter with button leter
                }
            }

        );
        eButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "E");
                }
            }
        );
        fButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "F");
                }
            }
        );
        gButton.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter(); // get random dropping letter
                    matchingLetter(rl, "G");    // compare dropping letter with button leter
                }
            }

        );
        hButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "H");
                }
            }
        );
        iButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "I");
                }
            }
        );
        jButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter(); // get random dropping letter
                    matchingLetter(rl, "J");    // compare dropping letter with button 
                }
            }

        );
        kButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "K");
                }
            }
        );
        lButton.addActionListener(
                        new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                String rl = lp.getLetter();
                                matchingLetter(rl, "L");
                            }
                        }
        );
        mButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "M");
                }
            }
        );
        nButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter(); // get random dropping letter
                    matchingLetter(rl, "N");    // compare dropping letter with button leter
                }
            }
        );
        oButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "O");
                }
            }
        );
        pButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "P");
                }
            }
        );
        qButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter(); // get random dropping letter
                    matchingLetter(rl, "Q");    // compare dropping letter with button leter
                }
            }

        );
        rButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "R");
                }
            }
        );
        sButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "S");
                }
            }
        );
        tButton.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter(); // get random dropping letter
                    matchingLetter(rl, "t");    // compare dropping letter with button leter
                }
            }

        );
        uButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "U");
                }
            }
        );
        vButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "V");
                }
            }
        );
        wButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter(); // get random dropping letter
                    matchingLetter(rl, "W");    // compare dropping letter with button leter
                }
            }
        );
        xButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "X");
                }
            }
        );
        yButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "Y");
                }
            }
        );
        zButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String rl = lp.getLetter();
                    matchingLetter(rl, "Z");
                }
            }
        );


        // add keyboard Listeners for each button through keyStup function
        keySetup(aButton);
        keySetup(bButton);
        keySetup(cButton);
        keySetup(dButton);
        keySetup(eButton);
        keySetup(fButton);
        keySetup(gButton);
        keySetup(hButton);
        keySetup(iButton);
        keySetup(jButton);
        keySetup(kButton);
        keySetup(lButton);
        keySetup(mButton);
        keySetup(nButton);
        keySetup(oButton);
        keySetup(pButton);
        keySetup(qButton);
        keySetup(rButton);
        keySetup(sButton);
        keySetup(tButton);
        keySetup(uButton);
        keySetup(vButton);
        keySetup(wButton);
        keySetup(xButton);
        keySetup(yButton);
        keySetup(zButton);
        keySetup(startButton);
        keySetup(quitButton);

    // display panel will display dropping letter or photos of alphabets....
    JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
    displayPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
    displayPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    // letter text field
    letterTextArea = new JTextArea(300,40);
    letterTextArea.setBackground(Color.white);
    letterTextArea.disable();
    displayPanel.add(letterTextArea);
    this.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
/*
    method: matchingLetter
    purpose: compare dropping letter and button letter that the user selected
             display message when matching or mismatch
*/
public void matchingLetter(String droppingLetter, String buttonLetter) {
    if(droppingLetter.equalsIgnoreCase(buttonLetter)) {
        //PlaySound ps = new PlaySound("sounds/backgroundmusic.au");
        //PlaySound ps = new PlaySound("sounds/cheer.wav");

        try {
                   audioUrl=new URL("file:" + new File(".").getCanonicalPath()
                                                 + "//sounds\\cheer.wav");

                   audioClip=Applet.newAudioClip(audioUrl);
                   audioClip.play();
               }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
               }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got It");
        rightButton += 1;
        rightButtonTextField.setText(Integer.toString(rightButton));
        Object source = startButton;
    }
    else {
        //PlaySound ps = new PlaySound("sounds/error.wav");

        try {
                   audioUrl=new URL("file:" + new File(".").getCanonicalPath()
                                                 + "//sounds//error.wav");

                   audioClip=Applet.newAudioClip(audioUrl);
                   audioClip.play();
               }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
               }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Letter");
        wrongButton += 1;
        wrongButtonTextField.setText(Integer.toString(wrongButton));
    }
}

/*
    method: ActionPerformed
    purpose: listen to buttons
*/
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == quitButton) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if (source == stopGameButton) {
        lp.stop();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you " + player + " for playing this game. Your Score is "
                                        + rightButton + " right and " + wrongButton + " wrong out of "
                                        + LearningLetterPanel.nLetterDropped + " letters");
        LearningLetterPanel.nLetterDropped = 0;
        rightButton = 0;
        wrongButton = 0;
        rightButtonTextField.setText(Integer.toString(rightButton));
        wrongButtonTextField.setText(Integer.toString(wrongButton));
    }

    /****************************************************
    * Start the game and resets the buttons to 0
    *
    *****************************************************/
    else if (source == startButton) {
        rightButton = 0;
        wrongButton = 0;
        rightButtonTextField.setText(Integer.toString(rightButton));
        wrongButtonTextField.setText(Integer.toString(wrongButton));
        lp = new LearningLetterPanel();
        JPanel displayPanel = lp;
        displayPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        this.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Font f = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 48);
        letterTextArea.setFont(f);
    }
}

 /***************************************************************************************
 * Assign  the <code> Component</code> keyListener to call matchLetter() with the associated letter
 * @param <code> Component </code> for any Component in the GamePanel
 ************************************************************************************/
public void keySetup(Component theCandidate){
     theCandidate.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() {
          public void keyPressed( KeyEvent ke ) {
            if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_A){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "A");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_B){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "B");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_C){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "C");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_D){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "D");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_E){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "E");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_F){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "F");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_G){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "G");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_H){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "H");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_I){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "I");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_J){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "J");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_K){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "K");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_L){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "L");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_M){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "M");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_N){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "N");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_O){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "O");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_P){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "P");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_Q){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "Q");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_R){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "R");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_S){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "S");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_T){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "T");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_U){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "U");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_V){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "V");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_W){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "W");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_X){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "X");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_Y){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "Y");}
            else if (ke.getKeyCode()==ke.VK_Z){matchingLetter(lp.getLetter(), "Z");};
          };
        } );
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `a.gif` stored in relationship to the classes? Is it on the file system (relative to the where the program is executed) or is it embedded within the program (jar or class path)

Comment: I believe it is relative to where the program is executed. In my src folder created by eclipse are my .java files and in that folder another folder called images, the gifs are all in that.

Comment: If it's in the `src` directory, then it will embedded/bundled with your program (in the jar or classpath).  Instead of `ImageIcon(String)`, you will need to use `ImageIcon(URL)` and `Class#getResource`, for example `aButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/a.gif")));`

Comment: Personally, I prefer `ImageIO.read` as it throws a nice `IOException` when things go wrong, unlike `ImageIcon` which can fail quietly, see [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: I put what you gave me in instead of what I had "aButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images\\a.gif"));" but it still gave me nothing

Comment: Im using Eclipse Mars right now

Comment: So, assuming that the images are stored in `src/images` then the above example should work.  Try exporting your program to a jar, then unzip the resulting jar to ensure that the images are been included in the jar

Comment: Hey you know what? I moved everything over to NetBeans and what you gave me worked!

Comment: Hey i'd like to thank you for this help btw.